# linear and nonlinear regression combined in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am working on data set where there are four predictors. There is good linear relation with one of the predictors but with other three i think polynomial would fit. Is there any method in python where i can predict single variable combining linear regression on one predictors and polynomial or other non-linear regression on other three predictors?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit one polynomial expression for all features which should take care of the linear one as well. The only difference is that the coefficient of the linear one will be of order 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try np.polyfit to see a potential trend in your data.
Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html